# Can we use a regex in the synonyms for LUIS list model?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I want to use a list model. Can I use the regex in the synonym list? For example:

```
{'canonicalForm': 'cat',
 'list': ['kitty',
  'c*']}
```

I want my model to return "cat" for "kitty", "cccccc", "chiuoiu", and any other string starting with "c".

Comment: When you say "any other string starting with c" do you really mean any string that `StartsWith` C like cave, century, city, corn, cube, cyborg, cheese, and cqwer, or do you mean a string containing only C's like the regex you provided: `c*`?

Comment: Are you still working on this?